# deleted csproj File by mistake

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I mistakenly deleted the csproj File in my project, and now I'm getting an error message :
[image]
now I don't know how can I restore it or make a new one, I couldn't find any file with csproj suffix in template files associating with this project file.

Comment: Go back to a previous commit in your version control system? If you don't have any, let this be a lesson to use one.

Comment: check your Recycle bin

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: create a new project and copy all files manually? And read up about VCS and git/bitbucket.

Comment: I did it but still getting the error messages I mentioned above.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I followed the below steps and it worked.

1. Create a new project
2. Copy its `.csproj` file into your folder
3. Rename the `.csproj` file to your project name